# PHP auto_prepend_file in CGI-MODE without modifying php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to do an `auto_prepend_file` on all requests to a folder using `.htaccess`.
The problem is, the PHP runs under CGI-MODE, and I cant modify any other php file or php.ini.
Tat's why I'm not using `php_value auto_prepend_file "/testing.php"` on the `.htaccess` file.

Is there any way of doing this under this specifications?

Comment: I will have only one php file in the www root dir, I've no permission to edit any file other then .htaccess files, and my php file on rootdir of course.

Comment: youre looking for [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server, you can do the following.

In your .htaccess add the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/testing\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /testing.php?url=$1 [L]
```

In testing.php, do whatever you want to do. At the end of the file, do something like this:

```
$file = $_GET['url'];
if( file_points_to_sensible_location( $file ) && file_exists( $file ) ) {
  require( $file );
}
```

`file_exist` is an existing function. `file_points_to_sensible_location(...)` is something you have to write. If you mess that up, someone might be able to execute or dump files you don't want to expose.

---

Edit: You can prevent this from happening for certain requests by adding additional conditions to the `.htaccess` file. For example: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|unicorn)$` will prevent the testing.php from being executed on files ending with that extension. A condition as `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$` would let it only work on requests ending with .php.

To make it work with wordpress, instead of `require( $file )` you can use `require( "index.php" )`. Since the url is the same, wordpress will still work.

To make it work with other rewriterules, you'll need to move the rewritelogic to your `testing.php`. You basically change `$file` to contain whatever it should contain after the rewrite and include/require that. Remove the corresponding rules from `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need something more compatible with any requests. In this case, if you request by an image, for instance, it will print on the screen the content but not the image.

Comment: If you mean you don't want to execute `/testing.php` when you request an image/css/js file, you can exclude those extensions in .htaccess (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|unicorn)$`). Alternativelly you can only execute it before other php scripts (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$`). This is the basic concept based on the requirements you have in the question. I can't really guess what other requirements you might or might not have.

Comment: But this will not work with other "SEO" rewrite rules like the ones find in a wordpress blog. The idea is to force the www root .htaccess file to execute my php before any other. I want to run a custom parsing & logging procedure on any request of my site. But I have no access to any configuration file like httpd.conf or php.ini

Comment: I can't test it here, but can't you just include index.php if it is a wordpress url?

Comment: I dont want to be fixed to work only with wordpress.

Comment: I have altered my answer a bit by adding tips how to go from here. As a programmer you are supposed to think through what you want to accomplish and find ways around obstacles you encounter, not wait there idly until someone spoon-feeds you the solution based on vague requirements and some unfinished thoughts.